# Group by array with key with another array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object:

```
var series = [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [1400, 999, 450],
    tag: "Tag 1"
}, {
    name: 'Series 2',
    data: [355, 188, 99],
    tag: "Tag 1"
}, {
    name: 'Series 3',
    data: [205, 488, 104],
    tag: "Tag 2"
}];
```

What I'm trying to do is to perform a groupBy function to that array so for example, calling **orderBy("tag")** should return the following output:

```
[{
    name: "Series 1 / Series 2",
    data: [1755, 1187, 549], // => Sum: Series1[0] + Series2[0], Series1[1] + Series2[1], etc...
    tag: "Tag 1"
},  {
    name "Series 3",
    data: [205, 488, 104],
    tag: "Tag 2"
}]
```

At the moment this is what I've so far:

```js
var seriesArray = [{
            name: 'Series 1',
            data: [1400, 999, 450],
            tag: "Tag 1"
        }, {
            name: 'Series 2',
            data: [355, 188, 99],
            tag: "Tag 1"
        }, {
            name: 'Series 3',
            data: [205, 488, 104],
            tag: "Tag 2"
        }];

const groupBy = (key) => seriesArray.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
  const newTotal = total;
  if (
    total.length &&
    total[total.length - 1][key] === currentValue[key]
  )
    newTotal[total.length - 1] = {
      ...total[total.length - 1],
      ...currentValue,
      data: parseInt(total[total.length - 1].data[0]) + parseInt(currentValue.data[0]),
    };
  else newTotal[total.length] = currentValue;
  return newTotal;
}, []);

console.log(groupBy('tag'));
```

As you can see it seems to work the orderBy("tag") but I'm doing the sum operation explicit, the main problem with this is that data[] could have X elements.

Comment: _"Another thing is that if I call orderBy("data") I want to show the array sorted based on all data[] elements sum"_, so you want your function to have different behavior based on the key the is passed to it?, ie: sometimes it groups and other times it just sorts? Seems like this should be in two separate functions and not in one imo...

Comment: @NickParsons I was thinking that too, so yes! You're right, I'll add another function called sortBy(), let me update my question to delete that requierement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your approach assumes that the last item that was added to your `total` array has the same `key` that you're trying to group on. This is all good if the data is sorted by `key` (ie: all "Tag 1"s come first), but can be an issue if its not. I would suggest that instead, you first build an object/`Map` that is keyed by `tag`. That way you can use the object to find your accumulated `"Tag 1"`, `"Tag 2"`, etc... objects. Once you've reduced it to an object/Map, you can grab the values (which are the accumulated objects) and put them into an array. To handle the different `data` array lengths, you can use `.map()` on your accumulated data array (ie: `seen.data`) and then add each number with the corresponding number from the current object's `data` array using the index argument `i`:

```js
const seriesArray = [{ name: 'Series 1', data: [1400, 999, 450], tag: "Tag 1" }, { name: 'Series 2', data: [355, 188, 99], tag: "Tag 1" }, { name: 'Series 3', data: [205, 488, 104], tag: "Tag 2" }];

const groupBy = (arr, key) => Array.from(arr.reduce((map, currentObj) => {
  const groupOnKey = currentObj[key];
  const seen = map.get(groupOnKey);
  return map.set(groupOnKey, seen ? {
    ...seen,
    name: seen.name + " / " + currentObj.name,
    data: seen.data.map((num, i) => num + currentObj.data[i], 0)
  } : currentObj);
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(groupBy(seriesArray, 'tag'));
```

Comment: Seems to be working, just one comment, how can I use that code but preserving the original seriesArray? For example I'm calling groupBy('x') when a dropdown value changes, the first time I get the grouped array but the second time I'm executing the groupBy function to that grouped array instead of the original seriesArray

Comment: @User1899289003 If I understood correctly, you can add an `arr` argument to the groupBy method, so then you can run the function on different arrays, passing the output of the previous call to the next call, eg: `const xArr = groupBy(seriesArray, 'x'); const y = groupBy(xArr, 'y');`

Comment: Yeah! I tried doing that but I don't know what's wrong. I'm trying to call the groupBy inside another function, basically I'm trying this: printArray(groupBy(seriesArray, 'tag')) => prints the result from your code snippet but then I call printArray(groupBy(seriesArray, 'name')) and it's grouping but with the array with first grouping results, here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4txyvc8h/

Comment: @User1899289003 calling `groupBy()` returns the new array, it doesn't modify the array that you passed into it. So in your example `seriesArray` never changes. If you want to update `seriesArray`, you can reassign it to the new array that was returned from the function call. Maybe something like this is what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/7g2nutkc/

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want, if you see this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ax61gkp5/1/ that's what I want, replicate both console.log() output but from the switch cases. If you change the selected option to tag the output it's okay, but when you change it to name then it's calling the doSomething function twice, the first one with the desired output (original seriesArray values) and the second one with wrong data (the same as if I'm calling groupBy("tag")

Comment: @User1899289003 I see, when you use `switch-case` statement, you need to use `break;` within the `case` so that when a case matches, the code will stop instead of "fall through" the other cases: https://jsfiddle.net/v496mLuj/

Comment: Omg, I can believe I was missing that, now works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Good challenge, this occurs to me with *findIndex*

```js
const groupBy = (key) => seriesArray.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
  index = total.findIndex(x => x[key] === currentValue[key])
  if (index >= 0) {
    total[index].data = total[index].data.map(function (num, idx) {
      return num + parseInt(currentValue.data[idx]);
    }); 
    total[index].name += " / " + currentValue.name;
  } else {
    total.push(currentValue);
  }
  return total;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic in your reduce callback function is not going to give you the result you want.
I'll explain what that function is doing.

1. First iteration total is an empty array as this is the initial value so the conditions is false and the else block is executed and adding the first element of the array to the new array
2. Second iteration total now has one element which has the same tag as the current element so if statement is true and code is executed which would override the first element, which is why name becomes Serie 2 instead of Serie 1 and data is a number instead of an array with the value equals to the sum of current.data[0] + total[0].data[0] = 1755
3. Third iteration if statement does not match and else block is executed adding the third element to total array.
   Also note that using total.length -1 is not covering the case when the second item doesn't actually match if you try to switch the order between serie 2 and serie 3 you will not get serie 1 and serie 2 grouped by tag.

What you want to do

```js
var seriesArray = [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [1400, 999, 450],
    tag: "Tag 1"
  },
  {
    name: 'Series 3',
    data: [1400, 999, 450],
    tag: "Tag 2"
  }, {
    name: 'Series 2',
    data: [355, 188, 99],
    tag: "Tag 1"
  },
];

const isMatchingArray = (array1, array2) => {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const groupBy = (key, array) => array.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
  const newTotal = total;
  if (total.length) {
    const matchingItemIndex = total.findIndex(element => {
      if (typeof element[key] === 'string') {
        return element[key] === currentValue[key];
      } else if (Array.isArray(element[key])) {
        return isMatchingArray(element[key], currentValue[key]);
      }
    });
    if (matchingItemIndex !== -1) {
      newTotal[matchingItemIndex] = {
        ...total[matchingItemIndex],
        ...currentValue,
        name: total[matchingItemIndex].name + ' / ' + currentValue.name,
        data: currentValue.data.map((dataItem, index) => parseInt(dataItem + total[matchingItemIndex].data[index])),
      };
    } else {
      newTotal.push(currentValue)
    }
  } else {
    newTotal.push(currentValue)
  };
  return newTotal;
}, []);

console.log(groupBy('tag', seriesArray))
console.log(groupBy('data', seriesArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const series = [
  {
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [1400, 999, 450],
    tag: 'Tag 1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Series 2',
    data: [355, 188, 99],
    tag: 'Tag 1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Series 3',
    data: [205, 488, 104],
    tag: 'Tag 2',
  },
];
const groupBykeyAndSum = (key, series) => {
  const grouped = series.reduce((acc, serie) => {
    const group = acc.find(g => g.tag === serie[key]);
    if (group) {
      group.name += ` / ${serie.name}`;
      group.data = group.data.map((d, i) => d + serie.data[i]);
    } else {
      acc.push({
        name: serie.name,
        data: serie.data,
        tag: serie[key],
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return grouped;
};
console.log(groupBykeyAndSum('tag', series));
```